# JQuery Compare Table Data

Tags: jquery, comparison

I have a large table of data (that displays test data) that is separated by date. I sort this data POST-processing using JQuery (the table is built in Perl and sorting really can't be done there). After this data is sorted by date, I would like to add a separating line between each day.

For instance, I'd like the five test runs from June 5th, followed by a blank line (a blank "tr", which will have data added to it later but that's not important here), followed by the June 4th runs, then a blank line, then the June 3rd runs, etc.

Here is a sample of a table I have: http://jsfiddle.net/pyUz8/1/

Here is the **pseudocode** I have, just not sure how to do this in JQuery:

> now = thisDate.substring(0,10) //Look at only the date, the time
>   doesn't matter then = previousDate.substring(0,10)
>
> If (then != now) insert(`"<tr></tr>"`); //inbetween then and now

How can this be done in JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run through each row, compare current date with next date, insert a tr after the current row if dates differ. Something like this:

```
$('tr').each(function(){
  var current_date = $(this).children('.date_cell').val() // or whatever you call your date cell
  var next_date = $(this).next().children('.date_cell').val() // also strip these evaluations from the time as you described...
  if (current_date != next_date){
    $(this).after('<tr class="blank_row"></tr>)
  }
})
```

Comment: What should have the "date_cell" class assigned to it? The table, the row, or the cell? -- Thank you, by the way.